# Counting characters in comments in c program

Tags: c, count, comments, character

Hi I'm trying to figure how to count characters in comments in c program. So far i had written a function that doesn't work, but seems logical. Can you please help me complete my task.My quest is to fill buffer with all the characters from the comments and then count them.

```
void FileProcess3(char* FilePath)
{
    char myString [1000];
    char buffer[1000];
    FILE* pFile;
    int i = 0;
    pFile = fopen (FilePath, "r");
    while(fgets( myString, 1000, pFile) != NULL)
    {
        int jj = -1;

        while(++jj < strlen(myString))
        {
            if ( myString[jj] == '/' && myString[jj+1] == '*')
            {
                check = 1;
                jj++;
                jj++;
            }

            if( check == 1 )
            {
                if ( myString[jj] == '*' && myString[jj+1] == '/')
                {
                    check = 0;
                    break;
                }
                strcat( buffer, myString[jj] );
            }
        }
    }
    printf(" %s ", buffer );
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: Check this condition: `if( check = 1 )`

Comment: Firstly modify `if( check = 1)` to `if( check==1 )` and test.

Comment: i corrected it, but the function still doesn't work :(

Comment: `strcat( buffer, myString[jj] )` does not do what you probably expect. It should give at least a compiler warning, because your second argument is a `char` and not a `char *`.

Comment: so how should i appernd myString[jj] to the end of buffer ?

Comment: Try `buffer[i++] = myString[jj];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. fix to

```
    int i = 0, check = 0;

...
            if( check == 1 )
            {
                if ( myString[jj] == '*' && myString[jj+1] == '/')
                {
                    check = 0;
                    break;
                }
                buffer[i++] = myString[jj];
            }
        }
    }
    buffer[i]='\0';/* add */
```

Comment: I managed to fill the buffer but i have some trouble looping through it.Could you please tell me how to loop and check if something is a symbol, because
`code
for( i =0; i<sizeof(buffer);i++)
    {
        if(isgraph(buffer[i]))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }  `
doesnt seem to work

Comment: Can be used as an index of character which has to write `i` is not used in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat()` concatenates (NUL-terminated) *strings*, so this is definitely wrong
(and should give a compiler warning due to the wrong type of the second argument):

```
strcat( buffer, myString[jj]);
```

You could do something like

```
buffer[length] = myString[jj];
buffer[length+1] = 0;
length++;
```

where `length` is an integer initialized to zero that keeps track of the current length.
Of course you should check the length against the available size of the buffer
to avoid a buffer(!) overflow.

If your intention is only to *count* the characters, then you don't have to copy
them to a separate buffer at all. Just increment a counter.

You should also note that `fgets()` does not remove the newline characters from the
input. So you have to check for that if you don't want to include the newlines
in the count.